# unit testing ionic2 - push not loading the page

Tags: typescript, angular, ionic2

We are developing an app in `Ionic2` and we already have a few tests, but now we are facing a problem with **push** method of the **NavController**.

We have a component called **TopicsComponent**. This component has a method called **selectTopic**. This method gets the selected topic and pushes another page onto the stack. Here is the code:

```
public selectTopic(topic: TopicModel) {
    if (topic.hasTopics) {
        this.nav.push(TopicsComponent, { target: topic.target });
    } else {
        this.nav.push(ModulesComponent, { target: topic.target });
    }
}
```

This is pretty straightforward logic:

*if it has topics, "redirects" to itself (TopicsComponent), otherwise, "redirect" to ModulesComponent.*

Now I need to test, once the "selectTopic" method has been called, the "TopicsComponent" should get called again, but this is not happening.

That is the test:

```
it("should get subtopics", inject([NavController, NavParams, XHRBackend, BackendService], (navController, navParams, mockBackend, backendService) => {
    // Arrange
    mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
        connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({
            body: {
                "id": "e0000001",
                "subject": "english",
                "type": "topics",
                "title": "Language Practice",
                "breadcrumb": "ENGLISH | TOPICS",
                "transitions": [
                    {
                        "transitionType": "next",
                        "conditions": [
                            {
                                "target": "e0000002",
                                "title": "Grammar",
                                "subject": "english",
                                "type": "modules"
                            },
                            {
                                "target": "e0000057",
                                "title": "Vocabulary",
                                "subject": "english",
                                "type": "modules"
                            },
                            {
                                "target": "e0000088",
                                "title": "Style",
                                "subject": "english",
                                "type": "modules"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        })));
    });

    var model = new TopicModel();
    model.hasTopics = true;
    model.target = "any";

    // Act
    let component = new TopicsComponent(navController, navParams, backendService);

    spyOn(component["nav"], "push").and.stub();

    component.selectTopic(model);

    // Assert
    expect(component["subject"]).toBe("english");
    expect(component["type"]).toBe("topics");
    expect(component["breadcrumb"]).toBe("ENGLISH | TOPICS");
    expect(component["title"]).toBe("Language Practice");
    expect(component["models"].length).toBe(3);
}));
```

Here is how I mock the **push** method of the NavController:

`provide(NavController, { useValue: { push: NavController.prototype.push } })`

It seems like the push mock is not working and that's why the "TopicsComponent" is not being called again. Any idea how to mock the push method properly?

**UPDATE**:

The **push** method will never call the page again as it's not a e2e test. I should simplify my test. I think I'm missing some test concepts.

Answer (score 0):

The test concept I was using didn't make much sense, I wanted to redirect and then check the result in the other page, but that is not an **e2e test**.

So, in this case I wrote two tests that covers what I was expecting:

```
it("should call TopicsComponent when topic has subtopics", inject([NavController, NavParams, XHRBackend, BackendService], (navController, navParams, mockBackend, backendService) => {
    // Arrange
    let model = new TopicModel();
    model.hasTopics = true;
    model.target = "any";

    spyOn(navController, "push");

    let component = new TopicsComponent(navController, navParams, backendService);

    // Act
    component.selectTopic(model);

    // Assert
    expect(navController.push).toHaveBeenCalledWith(TopicsComponent, { target: "any" });
}));

it("should call ModulesComponent when topic has no subtopics", inject([NavController, NavParams, XHRBackend, BackendService], (navController, navParams, mockBackend, backendService) => {
    // Arrange
    let model = new TopicModel();
    model.hasTopics = false;
    model.target = "any";

    spyOn(navController, "push");

    let component = new TopicsComponent(navController, navParams, backendService);

    // Act
    component.selectTopic(model);

    // Assert
    expect(navController.push).toHaveBeenCalledWith(ModulesComponent, { target: "any" });
}));
```